# Can I edit the Google maps api for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, edit

I want to edit it in order to add some TextViews in the map that I need. For example, a textview in top right corner with a real time information of location accuracy.

If you know a way to do it without modifying google maps api for android, please tell me.

I have read the terms of use os the service but i don't get a clear answer in if I can modify the maps jar.

Comment: you can't modify the .jar. Maybe you can @override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify the maps API. All you need to do is use a RelativeLayout as the root container of your layout and add a MapView and a TextView to it to display the text you want.

Here's a sample code

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <MapView 
  android:id="@+id/mapview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignTop="@id/mapview"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works really good, please edit the answer to correct the close of TextView tag, I can't do it because it less than 6 characters.